# Android app don't read default settings after installing

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I've developed an android application which has settings display with default preferences. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Voice settings">
        <CheckBoxPreference
                android:title="Voice"
                android:defaultValue="true"
                android:summary="Enable / disable voice in application"
                android:key="settings_voice" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

And I use it from an Activity:

```
SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
if (SP.getBoolean("settings_voice", true)) {...}
```

It works fine, after I went to settings display at least one time. 
**But**! **After first installing the application to the device, this parameter gets always "false" value, as long as I go (once) to settings display.** 
After doing it, it works as expected, even I exit and restart program. It stores the right value in the preferences.

Any idea for me, why it is working so strange? 
Thanks!!

Comment: Try to use this as SharedPreferences: ``getSharedPreferences("MY_APP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);``

Comment: Thanks, I try it. What should i write instead of MY_APP? I think is not the name of the activity.

Comment: Decide for yourself, it only should be always the same string.

Comment: Thanks, I found the error, in one place, I didn't use "SP.getBoolean("settings_voice", true)" with "true". Since I changed it, it works fine.

Comment: Anyway it very strange for me, that why the app doesn't find the parameter after install (and use the def. value in SP.getBoolean function), since I gave for the settings default value in xml ("android:defaultValue="true"")